# Android Google Maps API V2 Polyline

Tags: android, google-maps

I am working on Android for the first time and I am not as well verse in it.

What I am asking is how can I start to have my app to make polylines anywhere on the map so I can draw a polygon.

What I know so far is that I have to create a Polyline Object to do this and I need to create a list of LatLng points for my polyline function. This is where I am stuck. I have no idea how to go on from here.

I have looked at example code and the documementation at Google APIv2 I would step by step assistance on how can I achieve having my app draw polylines that can connect to be a polygon

Here is what I have on my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Polyline;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


public void draw(){
    //k is the list of LatLng

    Polyline draw = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(k)
            .width(5)
            .color(Color.BLUE));

}
```

}

Here are some images of what I like to have in the end[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my new code but it keeps giving me an error about mMap.setOnclicklistener; and when I run it, the app does not open.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private GoogleMap mMap;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initimap();
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(myOnMapLongClickListener);

}

private void initimap() {

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    mMap.setOnclicklistener;
}

OnMapLongClickListener myOnMapLongClickListener =
           new OnMapLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
             mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                  .position(point)
                  .title(point.toString()));

             Location myLocation = mMap.getMyLocation();
             if(myLocation == null){
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "My location not available", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             }else{
              PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
              polylineOptions.add(point);
              polylineOptions.add(
                new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));
              mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
             }
            }

         };



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

could someone take a look and explain what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

For your example it will be something like this.

```
Polygon polygon = map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
.add(new LatLng(22.154975,113.729675), 
     new LatLng(22.265587,113.822372), 
     new LatLng(22.188677,113.953521), 
     new LatLng(22.047459,113.904769))
.strokeWidth(5)
.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Comment: Well, the images are just examples. I want to be able to draw polyline anywhere on Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity{

 private GoogleMap myMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        myMap= ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map1)).getMap();


        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        myMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(myOnMapLongClickListener);

    }

 OnMapLongClickListener myOnMapLongClickListener =
   new OnMapLongClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
     myMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(point)
          .title(point.toString()));

     Location myLocation = myMap.getMyLocation();
     if(myLocation == null){
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
        "My location not available", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }else{
      PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
      polylineOptions.add(point);
      polylineOptions.add(
        new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));
      myMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
     }
    }

 };

}
```

**xml layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rl_Map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/rluserdetails"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Comment: If I tried this, would I have to put it under protected void onCreate or my public void draw?

Comment: you just have to put this method seperately in your Class. And write this in your OnCreate() - > mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(myOnMapLongClickListener);

Comment: the purpose of long click listener is to take the clicks on my map and use it as my laglng points for the polyline?

Comment: yes..you can do the same with onClick instead LongClick. It will take latlong of clicked position of map & draw polyline. Have this code in your project, run it nd then analyse. Then even you don't understand then come to me anytime.

Comment: I used mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(myOnMapLongClickListener) on the create function but I am getting an error about resolving a variable. What is the issue?

Comment: Plus what you meant about putting it to my class means I put the code under my public void draw function?

Comment: resolving a variable? which variable?

Comment: I think my error occurs do to I have to use fragment activity in my main activity. So I do have another question. Say I want to use onClicklistener for creating my polylines. How can I link them up to create a polygon?

Comment: see I am posting my whole activity as well as xml.

Comment: see ma updated answer.. Make a new project & copy paste this.

Comment: I am getting an error on FragmentManager myFragmentManager = getFragmentManager();MapFragment myMapFragment1 = 
          (MapFragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.map1); It is about not able to make a fragement to a map fragement

Comment: try by extending fragment Activity

Comment: Okay I added the changes but my app keeps crashing.